# What to install and download?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude, x3-terran-conflict, x3-reunion

I bought Albion prelude, Reunion and Terran Conflict but i am wondering which is the last in the series. Do they extend themselves and can I install/play them all at once? Other then that are there any free DLC's/mods I should install on top of it? I vaguely remember there was a free add on pack that adds some more items etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reunion was the first X3 game; Terran Conflict, the second; and Albion Prelude, the third and last. I would not recommend playing more than 1 game per 2 arms at the same time.

You can get the official addons called Bonus Packs from Egosoft's website – they add various command options for your ships

- [Reunion bonus pack](http://www.egosoft.com/download/x3/bonus_en.php)
- [Terran Conflict bonus pack](http://www.egosoft.com/download/x3tc/bonus_en.php)
- [Albion Prelude bonus pack](http://www.egosoft.com/download/x3ap/bonus_en.php)

Comment: It is usually recommended to just play Albion Prelude (with the bonus pack) as it includes all the previous plots, plus the Albion Prelude plot and additional features such as stock exchange etc. You'll need Terran Conflict installed in order to play Albion Prelude. Reunion need not be installed.

Comment: @UnderscoreZero AP does not include any plots from previous games.

Comment: http://www.egosoft.com/support/faq/faq_answer_en.php?answer=2167 I didn't realize that the TC specific plots are not be included but the Hub and HQ plots are still there. So that would be a reason to play TC.

Comment: @UnderscoreZero no, both TC and AP have plots that reward the player with the hub and the PHQ, but the plots themselves are different.

Answer (score 1):

Albion Prelude is the latest set, but you need Terran Conflict installed first IIRC.